# How to find specific private endpoint in azure powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm running this command in azure to pull private endpoints associated to a storage account:

```
Get-AzPrivateEndpointConnection -privatelinkresourceid /subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccountname
```

It returns results that look like the following:

```
Name                              : storageaccountname.93jd9v4a-84d3-942z-9g32-3895820193842
Id                                : /subscriptions/SubscriptionID/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccountname/privateEndp
                                ointConnections/storageaccountname.93jd9v4a-84d3-942z-9g32-3895820193842
GroupId                           : 
ProvisioningState                 : Succeeded
PrivateEndpoint                   : {
                                  "Id": "/subscriptions/SubscriptionID/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/PE1"
                                }
PrivateLinkServiceConnectionState : {
                                  "Status": "Pending",
                                  "Description": ""
                                }
LinkIdentifier                    : 

Name                              : storageaccountname.840ar94v-492s-594v-942s-49204816482941a
Id                                : /subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccountname/privateEndp
                                ointConnections/storageaccountname.840ar94v-492s-594v-942s-49204816482941a
GroupId                           : 
ProvisioningState                 : Succeeded
PrivateEndpoint                   : {
                                  "Id": "/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/PE2"
                                }
PrivateLinkServiceConnectionState : {
                                  "Status": "Approved",
                                  "Description": "2022-05-23: approved"
                                }
LinkIdentifier                    :
```

I want it to return just the one that has PE2 in the "PrivateEndpoint" parameter, so I run:

```
Get-AzPrivateEndpointConnection -privatelinkresourceid /subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccountname | where-object privateendpoint -like "*PE2*"
```

But it doesn't return anything.  If I run...:

```
Get-AzPrivateEndpointConnection -privatelinkresourceid /subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccountname | where-object privateendpoint -like "*"
```

...it returns them all.

How can I use where-object to return just the PrivateEndpoint with PE2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have also tried the same and getting the same issue as you and tried with below [**`where object format with id`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2) and it worked.

`Where-Object { $_.privateendpoint.Id -like "*PE1*" }`

***Nothing displayed:-***

[image]

***SUCCESFULLY GETTING DETAILS:-***

[image]

***Alternatively*** we can use the Given [**`REST API`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/private-endpoint-connections/get#code-try-0) here to get the same by using our private connection name:-

[image]

***STORAGE ACCOUNT DETAILS WITH PRIVATE ENDPOINTS:-***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any private endpoints to query but looking at the structure of the object it looks like you need the value of `Id`.

```
Where-Object { $_.privateendpoint.Id -like "*PE2*" }
```